# (Java / MYSQL) Checking user login in against MYSQL table, varables showing null even though data taken from table

Tags: java, mysql, if-statement, authentication, nul

Im using a GUI user login for a java application checking against a user table in MYSQL.

I have one record hard coded into the MySQL db with the username and password set to admin.

I'm trying to call this back and check it in my GUI but im having difficulty. im connecting to DB ok and storing the variables from db fine but then when i go to check them it shows the variables are null.

When i debug through the code i can see that in the doGetAdminUsers() method that in the variables are being populated within the while loops with the correct data.But then when i click the buttton to check the user entered login against the same variables they appear as null even though they are not declared locally.

Any ideas?

code below

//This method querys the DB for the name and password fields from position 1 of the table. which has allready been hard coded in

```
public void doGetAdminUsers() {

    String queryName = "SELECT name FROM users WHERE user_id = 1";

    String queryPassword = "SELECT pass_word FROM users WHERE user_id = 1";

    try {
        //connecting to DB 
        Statement st = conn.createStatement();
        //running the query and storying results 
        ResultSet rs1 = st.executeQuery(queryName);
        while (rs1.next()) {
            adminNameFromDB = rs1.getString(1);
        }

        ResultSet rs2 = st.executeQuery(queryPassword);
        while (rs2.next()) {
            adminPasswordFromDb = rs2.getString(1);
        }

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
    }

}
```

//This is the method for my launch button after user has entered their username and password in the designated GUI fields

```
private void LoginBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    name = userNameTf.getText();
    password = passwordTf.getText();


    if (name.equals(adminNameFromDB) && (password.equals(adminPasswordFromDb))) {
        myHomeGUI.setVisible(true);
    } else  
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Incorrect login name or password");
    }  
}
```

//doGetAdminUsers() method is called in main class which launches the application

Comment: **Don't** use `==` for `String`

Comment: Can you post a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (using `String#equals` ;o)?

Comment: updated if statement to string.equals . original issue still persists.